# SVN to work with one file in two different change lists

Tags: intellij-idea, svn, changelist

Is there such an opportunity in SVN to work with one file in two different change lists so that the changes made within each change list belong only to it?

Answer (score 2):

I had this query a few days back. I didn't look further on visiting this- https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/changelist-design.txt

There's a section that talks about overlapping changelists.

> A number of people ask "but what if two different changes within a
>       single file belong to different logical changes?"  My reply is:
>       either "tough luck" or "don't do that" or "checkout a separate
>       working copy".